# Between Constructive and Deconstructive Interference

Tags: waves, interference

Is there something other than constructive interference, such as a shift in 1/4 λ or 3/4 λ or even 7/5 λ?  Because it would not end in a hill or a valley.  It would be someplace between.  Would it still be considered constructive interference?

Comment: Where both waves have the same sign it's constructive, where they have different signs it's destructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you have a $\lambda/4$ interference at some point you will also have $0$ (aka constructive) $\lambda/2$ or $\lambda$ (aka. destructive) or whatever interference meaning that it depends on where you are currently looking on the screen. These not-overlapping valleys and hills will correspond to change in intensity of the light. (Note that the overlapping hills and valleys will also correspond to change in the intensity of light but that is I think rather obvious.) The intensity of light on the screen (for the famous double slit) is given by 
$$ I=I_0\cos^2\left( {\pi d \sin\theta \over \lambda} \right),$$
where $\theta$ the angle from the middle of the two slits to the point on the screen that you are considering is.